# Call ViewModel's fetch function with loading in Jetpack Compose called only once

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with coping simple flow in Jetpack Compose. The scenario is simple:

1. call `Composable` which draws screen and in its body call `viewHolder`'s fetch method.
2. `viewHolder`'s fetch method first post `isLoading.postValue(true)`
3. `Composable` shows loading animation
4. `viewHolder` calls repository to fetch data and
5. when receives it, sets `isLoading.postValue(false)` and posts fetched data
6. `Composable` shows fetched data

My problem is with constant reloading composable and calls to `viewHolder`'s calls to fetch data. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not cause side effects or change the state directly from the composable builder.

Instead you can use [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

In your case, [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) must be used. Also, it is already running on the coroutines scope, so you can safely call the suspend functions.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    viewHolder.fetch()
}
```

But even this is not totally "safe". In case of screen rotation `LaunchedEffect` will be relaunched too. I believe the only correct way is using a [view model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state) specific for a screen, and call `fetch` inside `init`.